# How to dynamically size distinct row columns in React to be the same

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have a table structure which is made out of distinct blocks **which cannot be brought into the same block**, such as this - only much larger.

The structure of this ideally needs to stay the same.

```html
<div class="dynamicList">
   <div class="header">
      <div class="item">col1</div>
      <div class="item">col2</div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
      <div class="item">Learn JavaScript</div>
      <div class="item">test message</div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
      <div class="item">Build something awesome</div>
      <div class="item">medium message</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I want a way to be able to dynamically size the columns in the row to auto fit to the text so that the largest text column width is used for all the others of the same column.  On the top is how it looks, at the bottom is how I want it to look.

[image]

I was hoping I could get away with just using CSS for this, however I feel I might need some JavaScript too.  I am using React, so thought about using useRef hook, but didn't know how well this would perform with a really large table.

What is the best way to calculate this width and then use it across all columns of the same index?

Here is a JS fiddle showing the problem.

https://jsfiddle.net/og8kz3hp/65/

Comment: Why aren't you using a table?

Comment: It's a much more complicated tree of components in real life with lots more going on, built up by various parts etc, this was just a very simplified example.

Comment: OK, but if it's meant to look like a table maybe use that option. Plus: _"but didn't know how well this would perform with a really large table"_ indicates you haven't investigated that route yet.

Comment: You can easily achieve what you want with few lines of Flexbox. I edited your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rf41yebk/8/, but I agree with @Andy. If it's a table, it would be semantically better to actually use HTML table tags.

Comment: React simplifies so much writing HTML, so don't worry about the repeating nature of table tags. React will make it look good.

Comment: @MoaazBhnas this doesn't dynamically adjust to the largest column.  This instead just sets specific widths for each column which is not what I want.

As mentioned this is part of a really large multi component list of rows which have a lot more going on than just some text.  

I could refactor to make it to a table if I really had to, but I was hoping there may be another way forward first

Comment: Aah, sorry. I thougt about a lot, and unfortunately as you said. The only way is using refs. Do you know how to go about this? I have a good experience with using refs. Let me know if you need help ..

Comment: I know basic refs, but not really when looking at trying to get the values from so many different columns at once and getting the max etc.  If you can point me in the right direction I would appreciate it.  I am also going to try and think about if I could refactor to use a table instead and try that method as I feel like refs may be unperformant with large amounts of columns/rows